# Match everything except my pattern (RegEx)

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried negative lookahead but not working. I am doing a mistake and I don't know where.

I have a date pattern and want to match everything except that pattern, like below.

**Hey how** 30.01.2019 **are you** 23.05.2020 **I am fine.** ==> (want to match bold areas)

my date pattern is that = `^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\.)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\.)(\d{4}|\d{2})$`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do numbers and dots ever appear in the desired content?  if not `([^0-9\.])` will work as a base regex.  You can modify with quantifiers to, e.g., `([^0-9\.])+`.  Probs not what you want, but maybe?  Here's a version with repeating groups ``((?:[^0-9\.])+)`

Comment: @varontron numbers and dots appears in the text.

Comment: A good solution with a plain pattern would be possible in PHP and a few others, but not in JS, I think. What are you trying to do with the matches? Do you want to replace them with something, or get an array of match strings?

Comment: I want to replace where date not appears

Comment: On occasion, I've run into this same scenario and each time I found it was just easier to look for all that does match the unwanted, then remove it and I'm left with what I initially wanted. You might want to consider going that route. Will make your logic a heck of a lot easier to understand if you ever need to revisit it.

Comment: `(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\.(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:\d{4}|\d{2})` will match all dates in the line.  You could combine this with substitution function,

Comment: Turn all capturing groups into non-capturing  and split with the regex. If string is needed as a result, just join the chunks back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern which matches *either* the date pattern *or* anything else, up until the start of a date pattern (or the end of the string). Then use a replacer function. If the match is the same format as the date, replace with the entire match (thereby leaving the string unchanged there). Otherwise, replace with whatever you need.

```js
const str = 'Hey how 30.01.2019 are you 23.05.2020 I am fine.';
const datePatternStr = String.raw`(?:[0-2]\d|3[01])\.(?:0\d|1[0-2])\.(?:\d{4}|\d{2})`;
const datePattern = new RegExp(datePatternStr);
const result = str.replace(
  new RegExp(`${datePatternStr}|.+?(?=$|${datePatternStr})`, 'g'),
  (match) => {
    if (datePattern.test(match)) return match;
    return 'foo bar';
  }
);
console.log(result);
```

The constructed pattern:

```
${datePatternStr}|.+?(?=$|${datePatternStr})
```

means:

- `${datePatternStr}` - Match the date pattern, or:
- `.+?(?=$|${datePatternStr})` - Match:

  - `.+?` One or more characters, as few as possible, up until lookahead matches:

    - `$` either the end of the string, or
    - datePatternStr

Note that you can trim your original pattern down to:

```
(?:[0-2]\d|3[01])\.(?:0\d|1[0-2])\.(?:\d{4}|\d{2})
```

(only use groups when they're required for the logic you need, `\d` can be used instead of `[0-9]`, and only use capturing groups when non-capturing groups won't suffice)

Answer (score 1):

An one liner for you:

```js
var string = "Hey how 30.01.2019 are you 23.05.2020 I am fine.";
var results = string.replace(/\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}/g,'%|%').split('%|%');
console.log(results);
```

**Description**: Replaced all the dates with `%|%` and after that splitted the string with `%|%`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @CertainPerformance's answer is matching my requirements more.